# Checking if an element exist

Tags: list, common-lisp

I'm stuck on a homework question. I'm trying to define a function that checks if an element exist in a list using recursion. Below is what I have.

```
(defun is-member2 (X S)
"Check if a X is a member of S"
(if  (and (atom X) (not (null S)) (lisp S) (> (length S) 0))

    ;X- is a value, not a set
    (if (equal X (car S))

        ;Located
        (equal 'a 'a)

        ;NotLocated
        (is-memeber2 X (cdr S))

    )

    ;No- X is not a value
    ()
);end if
)
```

However, I keep on getting that `is-memeber2` is undefined. This leads me to believe that either `X` is no longer a valid element or that (`cdr S`) is sending `nul`, but shouldn't my if statement catch this?

Comment: We're not using the `homework` tag anymore.  See the community bulletin on the right.

Comment: a suggestion for improving your current function:
`(defun is-member2 (element list-of-elements &key (test 'equalp))
(if (not list-of-elements)
    nil
    (if (funcall test element (first list-of-elements))
        (first list-of-elements)
        (is-member2 element (rest list-of-elements))))`

This would make your if-condition more readable and also allow you to parse lists containing sublists, as your current function would just aboard instead of continuing the search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is-member2` does not equal `is-memeber2`. Check your spelling.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked something so obvious. Thanks